# Why doesn't he following code works in inserting node at a specific postion in a Linked List?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Please take a look at the following code and let me know what's wrong with it? I'm trying to insert a node at a given specific position in a linked list. We need to return the reference to the head node after inserting it.

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = data;

    if(head==null){
        newNode.next = head;
        return newNode;
    }
    Node first = head;

    while(position > 0 && head.next!=null){
        head = head.next;
        position -= 1;
    }

    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
    return first;

}
```

Comment: The issues are all in those last 3 lines. You never assigned `newNode` to anything's `next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there is something wrong. After the `while` loop, you are trying to insert `newNode` BEFORE `head`, but this does not work. The line `head=newNode;` is useless.

Either you need another pointer to point to the node before `head`, so that you can insert `newNode` between these two pointers, or you need to stop the `while` loop one step before, and insert `newNode` AFTER `head`. Here is the second solution:

```
 while(position > 1 && head.next!=null){ //0 is replaced by 1 here
    head = head.next;
    position -= 1;
}

newNode.next = head.next;
head.next = newNode;
return first;
```

[EDIT]

In this solution, you need to handle the special case when `position` equals 0 by adding the following code just before the `while` loop:

```
if(position==0) {
    newNode.next = head.next;
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What if the position is 0 or 1? It's not working for that.

Comment: Poistion 1 works fine: the loop does not iterate at all and `newNode` is inserted after `head`, which is the correct position 1. As for position 0, you are right, it does not work. You need to add a special case for it. I will modify the answer accordingly.